# Android Junit Testing for Activity Flow

Tags: android, junit, integration-testing

I am new for Junit testing framework. Is it possible to test a flow of activities with assertions to check if each is launched using only exisiting classes provided in android API.
It seems we can only test at activity level. But can we automate a flow : like spawning front and back between activities ?

Comment: I dont know if you can do that with JUnit. JUnit is a unit testing tool and you are talking about flow testing on a system test level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, through the use of [Android instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/testing_android.html#Instrumentation), which provides you with methods that put you into the drivers seat when interacting with activities as the system would through it's instrumentation framework.

Basically, your able to trigger and manage every aspect of an activities life cycle, including introspecting results from activities calling each other. So if you've worked with the `ActivityTestCase` that's suitable when testing a single activity, you can have a look at the [`InstrumentationTestCase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html) that provides you with a low-level approach to work with multiple activities at once.

Comment: Yes I was stuck on finishing the newly launched activity from a click of a button, but Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor helps in this case, so one can move around to get a reference on newer activities and its views.